# Mongodb toCSV() function in Robo3T with nested items

Tags: mongodb, nested, robo3t

I am trying to extract data from a query in Mongodb with nested items.

Example:

```
{ '_id': 1111,
  'identity': {
    'name': 'John'
    'surname': 'Doe'
   }
}
```

We need a query to extract all surnames into a CSV. So, as I'm using Robo 3T tool, I create the .robomongorc.js file as explained here: [https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/How-to-export-to-CSV](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/wiki/How-to-export-to-CSV/)

And execute the following query:

```
db.collection.find({"identity.surname":1}).toCSV();
```

The results are like this:

```
"_id","identity"
"1111","[object BSON]"
```

How can I get the surname data as a string instead of this "[object BSON]"?